# Illustator - Scale bezier anchor point handle on every anchor point for an object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, bezier-curve

So I have the letter 0 hand written. Now I want it a bit fatter. But I don't know how to scale every anchor point handle and keeping it's symmetry. The only solution I could find is to do each handle one by one but I am afraid that it loses it's symmetry.

So scale the anchor point handle in each direction of the red arrows.

[image]

Bonus question: What is the correct name of the "handle" for an anchor point.

Comment: There's a programmer named Hiroyuki Sato. His script collection  http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#Exetnd contains many useful looking tools. Extend Handles seems to do what you want (= to see the result when handles are scaled at the same time as much) No guarantee - I haven't tried to run them. There can be obsolete ones due changes in Illustrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* scale the handles.

But, yes, you must do them one by one. That really shouldn't matter if you use *numbers* rather than trying to drag anything.

- Select one anchor using the **Direct Selection Tool** (White Arrow)
- Double-click the **Scale Tool** in the **Toolbar** and
- Use the `Uniform` field and enter a value.

The handles will scale.

[image]

If you select *more* than a single anchor, then the scale will also scale the distance between the anchors. So, one anchor at a time.

---

And the correct term for a handle is handle, or Bezier Handle, either is understood by users.

Comment: fantastic tip here, I didn't know that one can enter the values